# Pass xml field inside module's helper class

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, development, module, custom-module

I have a custom Joomla module. In the `helper.php` class, I need to pass XML field data.

Here is what I have so far.

```
class modcatbanerHelper {

    // I need to pass here 
    public $selected_cat = $params->get('title');

    public static function moduleCats($data)
    {
       #or pass here...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in your helper's methods the `$params` as a parameter.

```
public static function moduleCats($params)
{
   $title = $params->get('title');
}
```

Then when you call the method from your `mod_module.php`:

```
modcatbanerHelper::moduleCats($params);
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution helped me to pass xml field data to class in helper.php.

```
public static function xyz(){
    $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_name');
    $params = new JRegistry();
    $params->loadString($module->params);
    $xyz = $params->get('xyz');
    return $xyz;
}
```

1. mod_name -> this is the module name. Please replace this.
2. $params->get('xyz') -> this is the parameter found in module xml field. Please replace 'xyz'.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your snippet.  Ideally, all answers should include some plain English explanation of how/why it works or reference to documentation or fringe cases where the technique is not well suited.  In other words, please try to avoid posting code-only answers because these miss an opportunity to educate and empower future researchers.  You may [edit] your answer at any time.

Comment: This is not a good solution. It gets parameters of the first instance found in the database. So if you have multiple module instances, it will get the wrong parameters.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).